# Is there an upgrade path from ASP.NET 4 to ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, .net, owin, asp.net-core, asp.net-4.6

From what I gather, ASP.NET 5 is vastly different from previous versions in that most everything runs through the OWIN pipeline. Where does that leave apps written using ASP.NET 4.6 and before? Is there an upgrade path from ASP.NET 4.x to 5? Is this still a "one ASP.NET" thing where my 4.x style code will run side-by-side with the OWIN-based code? Anything you can elaborate on is appreciated.

Comment: No, yet. All I can say. Cut and paste might help a lot.

Comment: The new architecture does not "run through the OWIN pipeline". The pipeline is similar to OWIN and theoretically should be able to host OWIN compliant modules, but to say it is "OWIN-based" is not accurate.

Comment: @mason thanks for the clarification. much to learn about this new version.